# Generate Single Report while parallel execution in Nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have written browser automation test cases using Nightwatch. I have also implemented the 'phantomjs-prebuilt' for headless test cases. I am able to create a single report for all my test cases when I set 
'test_workers': {
        'enabled': false.
      }. However, when I set this to true it generate a single report but the data will be for last executed test suit only. It is overriding the other test suit.

Can anybody would able to generate a single report while executing in Parallel mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am facing same problem, will follow this thread. Just curious, what reporting tool are you using?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? Facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that you're running your Nightwatch command using the --reporter option. If you're still seeing only a single report created when running without --reporter then you have a different issue. Can you provide the Nightwatch command you are using to run your tests?

But based on the assumption, I came across a similar issue when using built in reports as part of the test command using '--reporter'.

My solution was to run a separate script after the tests have completed, pointing it at the directory the reports are saved in, it will then compile each XML into a single report.

Heres an example using nightwatch-html-reporter...

```
nightwatch --group <someGroupg> --env <env>; nightwatch-html-reporter -d /reports/  --output generatedReport.html
```

Hope that helps :)